# Select distinct items with a specific field in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dimensional array `ICs`.each row contains three fields category,name,description.I want to get all distinct category from this array.I had tried something like this

```
 var cs = ICs.Distinct(t => t.Category);
```

But its not working.Can any one give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ICS.Select(t=>t.Category).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 4):

Get all the values and then make a distinct set:

```
var cs = ICs.Select(t => t.Category).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. ;)

Try something like this:

```
var cs = ICs.Select(t => t.Category).Distinct();
```

I assume this is what you want - this will return all the distinct categories from the array.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version.

```
var value = (from n in ICs select n.Category).Distinct();
```

Hope it helps.